# Rabbit MQ cluster details from java

Tags: rabbitmq

I have installed rabbit mq on multiple nodes and clustered them. from the command line i can get the node status by calling rabbitmqctl cluster_statu. But I wanted to get the same details in java to log them. Can someone provide me a sample Java program to get the details on which node on the cluster is not running...Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [web management console](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html) API  .

Enable the console using:

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

then you can access to the API using

```
http://server-name:15672/api
```

Read [here](http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/rabbitmq_v3_4_0/priv/www/api/index.html) for more detail about the API.

At this point, you can call the API via java.

Answer (score 1):

You can try installing the management plugin which provides you the following APIs to interact with (from Java or whatever program you want):

http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/rabbitmq_v3_4_0/priv/www/api/index.html

the plugin docs are here:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html

Specifically, see the "monitoring" permission which can:

> List all virtual hosts, including ones they could not log in to via
>   AMQP View other users's connections and channels View node-level data
>   such as memory use and clustering View truly global statistics for all
>   virtual hosts

I'm thinking the data on the virtual hosts are what you are looking for, but you'll have to try it to be sure since the docs don't show the response data specifically. Note that vhost data may not be the same as the cluster info you are looking for.